# Problem in having similar words for Entities

Tags: similarity

[Issue for finding similarity of entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCnxR.png)

I want the most similar words for all the 'entities' that are available in my doc. I'm facing this error. I need assistance.It would be immense help for me if someone guide me. Thanks in Advance

Notes: Using 'gensim' to get the similar words for entities that are available in my doc
-Attached a screenshot of error.